# How to find angles of a triangle in L2[-1;1] space?

Tags: functional-analysis

How to find angles of a triangle whose vertices are $x1(t)\equiv0, x2(t)\equiv(1)$ and $x3(t)=t$ in the space $L_{2}[-1; 1]$ ?

Comment: 1) what is your definition of angle? It should use the scalar product. Just try plugging your functions in, and show how far you get.

Comment: 2) it seems x2=x3, so that is not really a triangle